# Dimension of Polynomial Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

We were asked in class of vector spces with infinite dimensions. Is it possible to say a vector space of all polynomials of all degrees is an example?

Comment: Yes. What are your concerns?

Comment: Take $f_n(x) = x^n$. Show that the $f_n$ are linearly independent. Take their span.

Comment: @copper.hat and that makes the basis of infinite cardinality which means the dimension of the vector space is so. Right

Comment: Yes.The choices are finite or not.